# Checking if linked tables can be viewed due to permissions/VPN in Access

Tags: sql-server-2008, vba, ms-access-2010

I have an Access database which has linked SQL Server 2008 tables. These SQL tables have some permission on them.

I want to find a good way to trap connection errors. These errors can from either:

- Permissions not being appropriate
- Unable to connect to database (off network, etc)

I was assuming I could simply use a DLOOKUP command on an arbitrary table and trap any error in the default form. However when I wrap a DLOOKUP like follows:

```
On Error Resume Next
currentVersion = DLookup(criteria)
Debug.Print err.Number
On Error GoTo 0
```

The error is not actually through in the VBA editor but rather at an application level and gets displayed:

[image]

This then prompts Access to show an ugly error prompt rather than trapping it only at VBA level. I get the results I need but want to avoid the prompt.

What is a way I can check whether a database is successfully linked or missing permissions?